# How to treat a system of bilinear constraints

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization, reformulation-linearization

A model contains constraints of the following form

$R(k) \leq X(k) G(k)$

where $X(k)$ binary and $G(k)$, $R(k)$ non-negative variables.

The index $k$ runs from $1$ to $50$.

I linearise the equations as they are products of binary and  continuous variables.

The question is, is there anything I can exploit to tighten the region these constraints define?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to enforce $X(k) = 0 \implies R(k) = 0$ and $X(k) = 1 \implies R(k) \le G(k)$.  You can use indicator constraints for that.

Alternatively, a straightforward big-M formulation yields
\begin{align}
R(k) &\le M_1(k) X(k) \tag1 \\
R(k) - G(k) &\le M_2(k) (1 - X(k)) \tag2 \\
\end{align}

A natural choice for $M_1(k)$ is a small constant upper bound $\bar{G}(k)$ on $G(k)$, and a natural choice for $M_2(k)$ is $\bar{G}(k) - 0$.  But notice that you can do better because $M_2(k)$ needs to be an upper bound on $R(k)-G(k)$ only when $X(k)=0$; in that case, $(1)$ forces $R(k)=0$, so you can take $M_2(k)=0$:

\begin{align}
R(k) &\le \bar{G}(k) X(k) \tag1 \\
R(k) &\le G(k) \tag2 \\
\end{align}

Depending on other constraints in your model, you might be able to tighten further.

Comment: Hi Rob. Thank you very much again! Your idea was very useful. Through further tightening I was able to solve my problem, which otherwise "refused" to converge to the global optimum.